# jqGrid - determine name of column on right click of a column in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want the name of the column on right click of a column header in jqGrid. Any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind `contextmenu` event to all column headers. Every header is `<th>` element and so its DOM support [cellIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp) property. The [cellIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp) property gives you the index of column header. If you would use the same index in `colModel` you will get the definition of the column. The `name` property gives you the column name.

The corresponding code could be about the following:

```js
var cm = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
$("th.ui-th-column", $grid[0].grid.hDiv).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    var $th = $(e.currentTarget).closest("th");
    if ($th.length > 0) {
        alert("the header of the column '" + cm[$th[0].cellIndex].name +
            "' was clicked");
        e.preventDefault(); // don't display standard context menu
    }
});
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RightClickOnColumnHeader.htm) uses the code. Just use the right mouse click on the column header and you will see the results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have a couple of more questions on jqGrid.

Answer (score 2):

All jqGrid cells have an `aria-described-by` property which is composed of `gridId_columnname`. You can use this to get your column name.

For grid cells..

```
var cellName = $(e.target).closest('td').attr('aria-described-by');
var gridId = 'list1';

var columnName = cellName.substr(gridId.length - 1);
```

For column headers, besides Oleg's answer, you can do this..

```
var header = $(e.target).closest('th')
var gridId = 'list1';

var columnName = header.attr('id').substr(gridId.length - 1);
```

Comment: On right click of a column header in jqGrid the `<th>` element will be as `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` and not the `<td>` element. The `<th>` element has `id` which are build in the same way as `'aria-described-by'` of `<td>`.

Comment: @Oleg: Agreed. I was proposing a solution for clicking anywhere in the column. Header or column cells.

Comment: I see that, but the question was "I want the name of the column on right click of a column header" and if one makes right clicks on the column headers the `$(e.target).closest('td')` will be not found. You can change `.closest('td')` to `.closest('td,th')` to have universal solution, but you should hake in the consideration that `<th>` elements has no `'aria-described-by'` attribute, but you can get the same information from `'id'`.

Comment: @Oleg: You're right. I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.