# Capture click activity on Column Header before postback?

Tags: jqgrid

On jqGrid is column headers at the top is where you click on it to sort the column ordering.

How do i detect the mouse click event?

The closest one I could find is this at [jqGrid - determine name of column on right click of a column in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291118/jqgrid-determine-name-of-column-on-right-click-of-a-column-in-jqgrid) but it deal with right mouse click.

I also saw jqGrid api "sortableColumns".

So, how do you people do this?

Thanks...

Comment: Is `onSortCol` callback what you need or you want to make some modification of the posted data?

Comment: That's it.  I make do with onSortCol.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `onSortCol` callback or `jqGridSortCol` event can solve your problem?