# jqGrid - determine name of column on right click of a cell in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

So i have to get the column name when open context menu which opens on right click on any cell in table. I found this answer [jqGrid - determine name of column on right click of a column in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291118/jqgrid-determine-name-of-column-on-right-click-of-a-column-in-jqgrid), which is only for column headers.

my code so far

```
loadComplete: function () {
                    $('tr.jqgrow').contextMenu('myMenu2', {
                        bindings: {
                            CA: function(trigger) {
                                var cm = $('#' + MY_GRID ).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
                                //CODE SHOULD BE ADDED HERE -- to get the column name and pass to addToContext();
                                var rowData = jQuery('#' + MY_GRID ).jqGrid ('getRowData', trigger.id);
                                addToContext(rowData);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
```

also tried this code but i get undefined

```
var cellName = $(trigger).closest('td').attr('aria-described-by');
```

Comment: Which version of `contextMenu` you use? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). In general you bind `contextMenu` to *every row* of jqGrid **separately** and do this on every filling of the grid. It's enough to bind the `contextMenu` *once* to the grid. Additionally you can use `onContextMenu` callback of `contextMenu`. The `target` property of the option `event` (`event.target`) gives you full information, which you need.

Comment: You would can use `var iCol = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td")[0].cellIndex;` to get the index of the column and `cm[iCol].name` is the column name.

Comment: @Oleg i use old jqGrid and jquery.contextmenu.r2.packed.js i will check your solution thanks for answer

Comment: @Oleg thanks it worked

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onContextMenu to determine the column name using the aria-describedby attrinute like this

```
    ....contextMenu('contextMenu', {
        bindings: {
            'edit': function (t,c) {
                console.log(colname)
                editRow();
            },
            'add': function (t) {
                addRow();
            },
            'del': function (t) {
                delRow();
            }
        },
        onContextMenu: function (event) {
            colname = $(event.target).attr('aria-describedby');
            colname = colname.substr(gridId.length + 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Where colname is defind globally and gridId is the id of the grid without #

P.S. In case of complex content in the cell the correct is to replace

```
$(event.target).attr('aria-describedby');
```

with

```
$(event.target).closest('td').attr('aria-describedby');
```

Comment: Did you define the colname globally? you should use `aria-describedby` and not `aria-described-by` as you post in the question, which is not correct

Comment: Ah sorry, your answer works also, gridId was undefined, i should of changed it with MY_GRID

Comment: @MasterYi Thanks. Glad to help.

Comment: Also $(event.target).closest('td').attr('aria-describedby'); should be used to get correct column name, thanks